# Genetic Algorithm with Top N solutions

Tags: java, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, jenetics

Basically I need to find the top N solutions of a genetic algorithm using Java (the solutions with the highest scores). I'm using the Jenetics library for the genetic algorithm, but I can't find how I'll be able to get those results without hacking the library's source code.

I can use another library if anyone knows a better one that has good documentation/examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the solutions by calling [getPopulation()](http://jenetics.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/jenetics/GeneticAlgorithm.html#getPopulation%28%29) and then you can sort them by the fitness function by calling [sort()](http://jenetics.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/jenetics/Population.html#sort%28%29) and then just iterate through the first N solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As all metaheuristics, genetic algorithms do not guarantee optimal solutions or provide any estimate of how good your solution is in comparison to the optimal solution. Therefore, I do not see a way to find the top N solutions using genetic algorithms.

Comment: The do compare solutions against each other though, so you can get the top N in the current population.

Comment: If the top N solutions of the current population are what is wanted, then of course your approach is the way to go.